# CouchDB _changes-API filter

Tags: filter, couchdb

I'm trying to get a filtered _changes-API stream on CouchDB 2.1.1 to work, but I run into issues.
I only want to receive documents via the changes feed that contain the field "type" with the value "article".

According to the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs/ddocs.html#filterfun) something like this should work:

```
function (doc, req) {
  if (doc.type && doc.type == 'article') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I created the function above in a new view called `type_article` in a _design document called `filters` using Fauxton. When I click on the view I don't see any results there.

Now I want to retrieve the filtered changes feed from the DB using the filter as a GET-parameter:
`localhost:5984/my_database/_changes?filter=filters/type_article`

The response of CouchDB is 
`{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing json key: filters"}`

Do you have an idea how I can get the filter-functionality to work?

PS: I also tried using the 'emit()' function instead of returning `true` and `false`, this returned the expected results, but when trying to query `_changes` the same error appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note, you actually can use view as a filter for `_changes`. In this case a document counted passed if a map function emits at least one record for it.

For example, if a design document (called "ddoc") looks something like this:

```
{"views":
    {"type_article":
        {"map":
            "function(doc) {
                if (doc.type && doc.type == 'article') {
                    emit(doc.name);
                }
            }"
        }
    }
}
```

Then a query would look like `localhost:5984/my_database/_changes?filter=_view&view=ddoc/type_article`. Note a missing `_design` prefix and a  keyword `_view` for an attribute `filter`. Here is a link on an according documentation section: [[link]](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/changes.html#view)

The only thing to be aware here is that this filter not actually using built view index and therefore not faster than an ordinary filter function.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. When you create a view in the Fauxton using small + sign next to the `Design Documents` menu entry you can only created views. Views are different than filters.
To create a filter that works with the _changes feed click on 'Create Document' and create a document like this:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/filters",
  "filters": {
    "type_article": "function (doc, req) {\n  if (doc.type && doc.type == \"article\") {\n    return true;\n  } else { \n return false; \n}\n}"
  }
}
```

This will create a new design document called `filters` with a function `type_article`.